# Kronecker product identity when multiplied by two vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares, kronecker-product

I am interested in least-squares optimization for problems with space-time separable prior state covariances and am trying to break down the quadratic cost function into respective space-time contributions. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Properties), we have that the mixed Kronecker matrix-vector product can be written as:

\begin{align}
\left( \mathbf{A} \otimes \mathbf{B} \right) \mathbf{v} = \operatorname{vec} (\mathbf{B} \mathbf{V} \mathbf{A}^T)
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{V} = \operatorname{vec}^{-1}(\mathbf{v})$ is the inverse of the vec() operator (formed by reshaping the vector $\mathbf{v}$).

Is there a similar simplification for the product (yielding a scalar)

\begin{align}
\mathbf{v}^\top \left( \mathbf{A} \otimes \mathbf{B} \right) \mathbf{v}
\end{align}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. In general,
$$
\operatorname{vec}(A)^\top\operatorname{vec}(B) = \operatorname{tr}(A^\top B).
$$
It follows that
$$
v^\top (A \otimes B)v = \operatorname{vec}(V)^\top\operatorname{vec}(BVA^\top) = \operatorname{tr}(V^\top BVA^\top).
$$